# Remove attribute from JSON objects in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of json objects.

```
var user =[ { id: 1, name: 'linto', img: 'car' },
  { id: 2, name: 'shinto', img: 'ball' },
  { id: 3, name: 'hany', img: 'kite' } ]
```

From this is want to remove attribute img from all the elements of the array, so the output looks like this.

```
var user =[ { id: 1, name: 'linto' },
  { id: 2, name: 'shinto' },
  { id: 3, name: 'hany' } ]
```

Is there a way to do this in java script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

You can use `map()` in the following way:

```js
var user =[ { id: 1, name: 'linto', img: 'car' },
  { id: 2, name: 'shinto', img: 'ball' },
  { id: 3, name: 'hany', img: 'kite' } ]
  
user = user.map(u => ({id: u.id, name: u.name}));
console.log(user);
```

Comment: can we add some kind of condition while doing the mapping? Like if we want to check Id is null or not.

Comment: @SouradeepBanerjee-AIS, `map()` is designed to iterate over all the array items and you can manipulate the items based on some condition. If you want to filter out some items then you can use `filter()`:)

Comment: Thanks, I used the filter function and was able to do it.

Comment: @SouradeepBanerjee-AIS, you are most welcome:)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `.map()` with Object Destructuring:

```js
let data =[
  { id: 1, name: 'linto', img: 'car' },
  { id: 2, name: 'shinto', img: 'ball' },
  { id: 3, name: 'hany', img: 'kite' }
];
  
let result = data.map(({img, ...rest}) => rest);

console.log(result);
```